# React component class vs ordinary javascript class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whats the difference, in terms of speed and performance of these two implementations:

```
export const MyComponent = ({ args }) => {
  ...
}
```

And:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Specifically about the render function in both of them.

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for? Real performance difference depends on the specific environment the code is running. If you are curious which one performs "better" in your specific use case, [profile your code](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will React 0.14's Stateless Components offer performance improvements without shouldComponentUpdate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33703817/218196)